# Jumping stick on a rough surface

Tags: classical-mechanics

I have long observed an interesting phenomenon of a
[jumping stick](https://youtu.be/xxaNZdVY5lA). If you drive a stick along a rough surface, then the stick does not move smoothly, but in jumps (as in the video).

Is any physical explanation of this phenomenon?

---

A similar phenomenon, I think, occurs with chalk, which can be drawn on a blackboard in such a way that it [draws dashed lines](https://youtu.be/GhawwXcQsUs).

Comment: Lookup [Painleve paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painlev%C3%A9_paradox).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a combination of friction and non-perfect vertical alignment of the stick, that makes the contact with the wall introduce bending into the stick itself.

When the friction and the normal reaction can't sustain the bending moment needed for the equilibrium, the stick goes into dynamic regime until the combination of friction and normal reaction can sustain again a new static condition.

If you press quite hard on the stick, instability of the stick itself may play a major role.

Answer (score 1):

If the stick were rigid, it would slide smoothly over the surface once the horizontal component of the force applied by the person exceeds the maximum possible static friction force between stick and the surface given by

$$f_{static-max}=\mu_{s}N$$

Where $N$ is the normal reaction force of the surface due to the downward component of the person's applied force (plus the "weight" of the stick, which is probably negligible) and $\mu_s$ is the coefficient of static friction between the stick and the surface.

But as can be seen, the stick is flexible. The combination of the  force applied by the person at the top and the reaction force on the bottom causes the stick to bend with resulting  compressive and tensile bending stresses. So instead of the stick sliding smoothly when the maximum static friction force is exceeded, it jumps off the surface like a spring relieving the bending stresses.

Hope this helps.